# chrome's console.log string substitution seems out of control

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to show a string using console.log.
I just want to show the string
(*not* have it [interpreted as a format string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console#using_string_substitutions)).

Example string: `'here are two percents: %%'`

My attempts to print it (google-chrome Version 100.0.4896.127):

```
  console.log('here are two percents: %%')
  // wrong output: 'here are two percents: %'

  console.log('%s', 'here are two percents: %%')
  // wrong output: 'here are two percents: %'

  console.log('%s', '%s', 'here are two percents: %%')
  // wrong output: 'here are two percents: %'

  console.log('', 'here are two percents: %%')
  // wrong output: ' here are two percents: %%'
```

Note the undesired leading space, in the last attempt.

How can I get the desired output `'here are two percents: %%'` ?

Answer (score 1):

For one thing, what you're seeing is a Chrome-specific problem (I'd even go as far as to call that a bug, you should report it). On Firefox, the output is much more sane:

[image]

However, a portable way to get your string printed as is is to use `console.dir()` instead, that seems to work on both Chrome and Firefox as expected.